# Cryptic Crossword (4 x 4)

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

I just created a small (4 x 4) Cryptic Crosswords grid :

[image: http://imgur.com/a/9wikJ]

### Clues

**Down**

> 1- Digging starts primarily with scant. (4)
>   3- Los Angeles is the center of an oval melting rock. (4)
>   5- Old Poem concludes better : a German alternative. (4)
>   7- British ring of rubber? Thank you, half-Sire. (4)

**Across**

> 2- Scenario begins pretentiously with a large number. (4)
>   4- Girl's a dude?! Why?! (4)
>   6- Above strange ore mixed with unending vice. (4)
>   8- Be careful of the goods. (4)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answers are, in numeric order:

> 1. PLOW=P(rimarily)+LOW.
>  2. PLOT=P(retentiously)+LOT
>  3. LAVA=LA+(o)VA(l).
>  4. LADY=LAD+Y.
>  5. ODER=ODE+(bette)R (which is German for 'OR')
>  6. OVER=(ORE+V)*
>  7. TYRE=TY+(si)RE.
>  8. WARE, double definition

The filled up grid looks like:

> [image]